# Insert multiple checkbox value using jquery and ajax but only inserted one record

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here If i select Both checkBoxes Only bed val is inserted
I want both the values to be inserted.

```js
$("#btnSubmit11").click(function() {

  if ($('#chkbed').is(':checked'))

  {
    FacilitiesGiven.Type_of_Facilities = $("#chkbed").val();
    if ($('#chkpillow').is(':checked'))
      FacilitiesGiven.Type_of_Facilities = $("#chkpillow").val();
  }


  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "WebService.asmx/FacilitiesGiven_insert1",
    data: '{fg: ' + JSON.stringify(FacilitiesGiven) + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    error: OnErrorCall
  });
});
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Thank you i will do ,,iam new here

Comment: So. Please click edit, then `[<>]` and give us the relevant HTML and event handling to see what the problem is